# Delegate Being Sent To Parent Class instead of Pushed class

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

A weird situation arises while using delegates in iOS.
A delegate method send its control to different class rather than calling class implemented same delegate method.

Example :

I am having a Dashboard which is calling a web service (a different class implemented all web service calls). In dashboard global web service class object exists with delegate self. When we call a web service the control comes to this class. So thats fine.

Now i am having another class which got push from dashboard or some time from other view controllers as well and it is also calling same web service. It is having its own web service class object globally and set delegate to self.
When I am calling web service from this class with its web service object after web service call control goes to delegate of dashboard not to this class though call has been made from this class and delegation is set to self.

This situation arises to many place where pushed child also implemented the same delegate method which its previous class has also implemented and thus instead delegation called of pushed class the method is called of the previous class.

Here is the main lines of code explaining above example :

WebServiceCaller.h

Class handles all web services caller

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "WebserviceEnum.h"

    @protocol WebServiceCallerDelegate;

    @interface WebServiceCaller : NSObject
    {
        __unsafe_unretained id <WebServiceCallerDelegate> delegate;
        NSOperationQueue * operationQueue;

    }
    @property(nonatomic, assign) id <WebServiceCallerDelegate> delegate;

    -(void)cancelWebserviceCall;

    -(void)cancelAllCalls;

    #pragma mark - Class Methods

    -(void)getListOfAnalyticQuestionsOfUserID:(NSString*)userid;
@end

#pragma mark - Protocol Methods

@protocol WebServiceCallerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional


-(void)getListOfAnalyticQuestionsCompletesSuccessfully:(BOOL)success WithList:(NSMutableArray*)arrQuestions WithMessage:(NSString*)message;


@end
```

WebServiceCaller.m

When after webservice call result will be sent to calling class.

```
-(void) getListOfAnalyticQuestionsOfUserID:(NSString*)userid{

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?user_id=%@",[self getURLWithBase:BaseURL relativeURL:@"wt_question.php"],userid];

  //webservice  call goes here and after completion calls below method
}


   -(void)getListOfAnalyticQuestionsCalledSuccessfully:(BOOL)success WithData:(id)Data WithMessage:(NSString*)errorMessage{

    NSDictionary *dictResult = (NSDictionary*)Data;
    NSMutableArray *arrAnalytics = nil;
    NSString *message = errorMessage;
    if (success) {
        arrAnalytics = [dictResult objectForKey:@"items"];
        message = SuccessMessage;
    }
    else{
        if (message.length==0) {
            message = NETWORKERRORMESSAGE;
        }
    }
    if(self.delegate!=nil && [(id)[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(getListOfAnalyticQuestionsCompletesSuccessfully:WithList:WithMessage:)])
    {
        [(id)[self delegate] getListOfAnalyticQuestionsCompletesSuccessfully:success WithList:arrAnalytics WithMessage:message];
    }

}
```

Code snippets from calling class suppose class B, same implementation has been done in class A also from which B has been pushed so every thing is working fine instead of sending control to class B control is sent to class A (webServiceCaller object is created in class A in same manner as in class B and calling same web service, This is just an example same thing happened for other web services too. which is implemented by both pushed and its previous class.)

```
#import "WebServiceCaller.h"

#define numberOfRecordsPerPage 15

@interface AnalyisViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,WebServiceCallerDelegate>
{
    NSInteger currentIndex;
    NSDictionary *dictQuesList;
    NSInteger totalPages;
    NSMutableArray *arrQuestionList;
       WebServiceCaller *webServiceCaller;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
webServiceCaller = [[WebServiceCaller alloc]init];
    webServiceCaller.delegate = self;
  [self showQuestions];
}
-(void)showQuestions{
    [ProgressHUD show:@"Loading..." Interaction:NO];
    [webServiceCaller cancelAllCalls];
    [webServiceCaller getListOfAnalyticQuestionsOfUserID:userid];
 }
#pragma mark -  Webservice delegate

-(void) getListOfAnalyticQuestionsCompletesSuccessfully:(BOOL)success WithList:(NSMutableArray*)arrQuestions WithMessage:(NSString*)message{
   //Handles my stuff
}
@end
```

Any idea of this weird situation.

Comment: Please provide some code showing any inheritance, and how the delegate is defined.

Comment: You keep saying global... Sounds like you have a logical error with global scope state management. Why are you using global anything?